# Substracting values in dataframe based on date

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
ID  Date       Paid  Due
A  2019-07-01  40000 50000
B  2018-08-20  1500  9000
B  2018-08-20  2500  9000
B  2018-09-18  3000  9000
C  2018-10-03  1000  2000
C  2018-10-30  1000  2000
D  2018-08-20  2000  3000
```

Now I'm trying to substract the values based on the month (and based on ID), so I need to create new column 'Month remanining' and the values that remain after subsctracting transfer over to the next month:

```
ID  Date       Paid  Due     Month     Month_Remaining
A  2019-07-01  40000 50000  2019-07      10000
B  2018-08-20  1500  9000   2018-08      7500
B  2018-08-20  2500  9000   2018-08      5000
B  2018-09-18  3000  9000   2018-09      2000
C  2018-10-03  1000  2000   2018-10      1000
C  2018-10-30  1000  2000   2018-10      0
D  2018-08-20  2000  3000   2018-08      1000
```

Is it possible in Pandas?

Comment: So the base value is the one that is in `Due` column. Now in every month there are some payments for the items in `ID`. After substracting the `Paid` value from `Due` i put the updated value in Month_Remaining column. For the next date(next month) for that ID i substract `Paid` from `Month_Remaining` value for that `ID`.

Comment: The group `B` is confusing. Why is `9000 - 1500 = 6500`? I think you want `7500` there.

Comment: Yeah fixed, sorry

Comment: Why do you consider month `9` with `8` as the same group for `ID B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Date` is a plain string, you can build the `Month` column with either:

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strfime('%Y-%m')
```

or

```
df['Month'] = df['Date'].str.slice(0,7)
```

If it is a `Datetime` columns, you can use:

```
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.strfime('%Y-%m')
```

You can then build the `Month_Remaining` column with:

```
df['Month_Remaining'] = df['Due'] - df.groupby(['ID'])['Paid'].cumsum()
```

You should finaly get:

```
  ID        Date   Paid    Due    Month  Month_Remaining
0  A  2019-07-01  40000  50000  2019-07            10000
1  B  2018-08-20   1500   9000  2018-08             7500
2  B  2018-08-20   2500   9000  2018-08             5000
3  B  2018-09-18   3000   9000  2018-09             2000
4  C  2018-10-03   1000   2000  2018-10             1000
5  C  2018-10-30   1000   2000  2018-10                0
6  D  2018-08-20   2000   3000  2018-08             1000
```